# How to use i18n code template in Java instead of JSTL in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Current spring MVC application integrate `i18n` and `JST`L for constant String message/labels. Here has some work around needed to get the `code template` in the `service layer`, so that can pack all label values in `String ArrayList`

for example:

in `message.properties`, there are list of properties:

```
task_START=Start
task_ORDER=Order
task_CANCEL=Cancel
.....
task_FINISH=Finish

task.list=START,ORDER,FINISH
```

Now in service layer I need to break down above `task.list` and take the code template `task_[value]`(this is format from JSTL, but not sure this works in Java code) to put all breakdowns as String ArrayList:

```
{"Start", "Order", "Finish"}
```

In my code I already have:

```
@Value("${task.list}")
String taskString;

List<String> tasks= new ArrayList<String>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String[] taskArray = taskString.split(",");
    for(String task:taskArray){
            // need match code template here
        tasks.add(task.trim()); 
    }
    Collections.sort(tasks);
}
```

Above code need template match to inject exact property value instead of property name into the list, but how to achieve this, just like in JSTL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just inject [`MessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) and and use one of its [`getMessage`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html#getMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Locale%29) methods like:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;


someMethod(){
    String task = ...;
    String code = messageSource.getMessage("task_["+ task +"]", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```

Comment: a little add up to @madhead's answer: I use "task_"+ task instead of "task_["+ task +"]" and it works fine...